# Is there a way to "EXPLAIN" a Cassandra query?

Tags: optimization, cassandra

As titled. I want to know whether my query is well optimized.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes, in Cassandra 1.2 you can turn on [request tracing](http://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/tracing-in-cassandra-1-2) for queries.